# In Laravel8 cant use Lang method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, lang

I want to use Laravel Lang method in with parameters. But it is giving error.

```
return view('backoffice/index')
    ->with('orderstatus','{{Lang::get('saide.version')}}')
    ->with('paymentstatus',Lang::get('saide.version'));
```

How can i solve this problem ??

**Errors**
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Lang' not found

Answer (score 1):

```php
return view('backoffice/index')
        ->with('orderstatus', \Lang::get('saide.version') )
        ->with('paymentstatus', \Lang::get('saide.version') );
```

Try the above one. You don't use `'{{ }}'` when you are in controller.

`\Lang::get('saide.version')` this will return the string and it will set the string value to `orderstatus`. Which will pass to the blade file